# Problemas em instalar o cakePHP no linux ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, linux, cakephp

Estou com problemas em instalar o cakePHP no linux. Quando executo o comando `composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app [app_name]` aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> ```
>     Installing cakephp/app (3.5.0)
>   - Installing cakephp/app (3.5.0)
>     Loading from cache
>
> Created project in cakePHP
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
>   Problem 1
>     - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp 3.5.* -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.5.0].
>     - cakephp/cakephp 3.5.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>   Problem 2
>     - cakephp/bake 1.1.3 requires cakephp/cakephp >=3.1.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.5.0].
>     - cakephp/bake 1.1.4 requires cakephp/cakephp >=3.1.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.5.0].
>     - cakephp/bake 1.2.0 requires cakephp/cakephp >=3.2.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.5.0].
> segue abaixo uma imagem do erro
> ```

[image: erro de instalação cake]

Comment: Copia a mensagem do erro do terminal e cola na pergunta ao invés de postar fotos, assim usuários que fizerem busca pelo erro escrito poderão encontrar a sua pergunta e resposta e se beneficiarem da informação.

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver apenas utilizei o seguinte comando no terminal linux `sudo apt-get install php-intl` ele irá instalar as extensões "intl" do php. Em seguida, deletar o projeto cake que você tentou instalar e instale novamente.

Segue o link que me ajudou a resolver o problema: [Resolvendo problemas da extensão "intl" na instalação do cakephp](https://www.jasonsnider.com/posts/view/php-intl-on-ubuntu-for-cakephp-3-and-php-7)